# How to loop over all rows in a dataframe based on given columns and then produce a dictionary of the results?

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` like this:

```
0      Main_1      Main_2        Date1       Date2      ....     Date99  
1      1994-11-05  1997-11-07    1993-11-07  1994-11-07          2002-11-07
2      1994-1-07   1997-11-07    1993-11-07  1999-11-07          2002-10-07
3      1994-8-09   1997-11-07    1999-11-07  2000-11-07          2003-11-07
.      .           .             .           .                   .
.      .           .             .           .                   .
30,000 .           .             .           .                   .
```

> Main_1: A column with dates.
>
> Main_2: Another date column.
>
> Date1 to Date99 : 99 Date columns. These 99 columns have different dates, and they are sequential. That is Date 1 is earlier than Date2, Date2 is earlier than Date3 and so on for each row. Date99 denotes the latest date for a row.

What I am trying to do is create a loop for each row that checks:

- Columns from `Date1` to `Date99` to see if the value date is between (or equal to) `Main_1` and `Main_2` events.
- If the value is between (or equal to) `Main_1` and `Main2`, records the name of the related Date column, like `Date78`, `Date79`, `Date80`.

For example, let's assume only `Date90`, `Date91`, and `Date92` fits the condition for the first row, I would like to see a dictionary, such as:

```
{
    (row0: Date90, Date91, and Date92)
    (row1: DateX, DateY)
    .  
    .  
    row30000: DateK, DateM, DateN, DateZ)
}
```

Note: Columns were created using `pd.to_datetime` with `format='%Y/%m/%d`.

Therefore, I want to know which Date columns (they all indicate an incident) happened between these main events for each row in my data frame. I tried to do using itertools but so far I failed so I appreciate if anyone guide me on this!

My failed attempt:

```
Date_sequence={}
for item, frame in sample_data.ix[:,2:102].iteritems():
    if frame>=sample_data.ix[:,1] and frame<=sample_data.ix[:,2]:
        Date_sequence['item'] = frame
```

Comment: If you can tell me which part is unclear, I will try to clarify. My code did not take me anywhere.

Comment: I typed some code in the edits. Thanks for the response.

Comment: ok, posted a possible solution and removed close vote + obsolete comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.dataFrame.apply()` to process each row in turn. For each row you can gather the names of the columns and test the row value for inclusion in the date range.

**Code:**

```
def find_dates_in_range(row):
    start = row.Main_1
    end = row.Main_2
    return [column for column in row.index.values[2:]
            if start <= row[column] <= end]
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
    u"""Main_1      Main_2      Date1       Date2       Date3
      1994-11-05  1997-11-07  1993-11-07  1994-11-07  2002-11-07
      1994-01-07  1997-11-07  1993-11-07  1999-11-07  2002-10-07
      1994-08-09  1997-11-07  1995-11-07  2000-11-07  2003-11-07
    """), sep='\s+',
    parse_dates='Main_1 Main_2 Date1 Date2 Date3'.split())

print(df.apply(find_dates_in_range, axis=1))
```

**Results:**

```
0    [Date2]
1         []
2    [Date1]
```

**Make me a dict:**

And to transform into the form asked for in the question:

```
results = df.apply(find_dates_in_range, axis=1)
as_a_dict = {'row%s' % i: v for i, v in enumerate(results)})
print(as_a_dict)
```

gives:

```
{'row0': ['Date2'], 'row1': [], 'row2': ['Date1']}
```